# pymongo query by datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo

I got one problem which made me headache for almost one day.

The python scripts are:

```
# coding:utf-8
import pymongo
import datetime, time

def query_data(IP,datefrom,dateto):
    conn = pymongo.MongoClient(IP)
    db = conn.mymongo

    startdate = time.mktime(time.strptime(datefrom,'%Y-%m-%d'))
    enddate = time.mktime(time.strptime(dateto,'%Y-%m-%d'))

    # all above are correct definitely.
    #
    # but I got no result from this line below.
    cursor = db.find({'username':'test','created':{'$gte':startdate,'$lt':enddate}})
    print cursor.count()
    # with above code, I got 0 returned though I can see it is nonzero in database.
    # 
    # If I use this below with single datetime, I can see result. But it is not my intention.
    # cursor = db.find({'username':'test','created':datefrom})
    # print cursor.count()

    tempData = []
    for doc in cursor:
        print doc['twitter']
        tempData.append(doc['twitter'])

    print len(tempData)
    return tempData

result = query_data('192.168.100.20','2014-4-1','2014-5-1')
```

The question is what was wrong with my code above?
Or how can I query data from mongoDB between two dates, with pymongo script?

Comment: In mongodb, the datetime should be `ISODate` object, try comparing `new Date(...)` instead

Comment: I have tried in two ways:
    db.find({'username':'test','created':{'$gte':new Date(datefrom),'$lt': new Date(dateto)}})
and
    db.find({'username':'test','created':{'$gte':'new Date(datefrom)','$lt': 'new Date(dateto)'}})

Either way gave me no results. Did I use a wrong format there?

Comment: Have you tried just using `datetime.datetime`?

Comment: @Anzel yes, i did but with this format datetime.datetime(2014,3,1) for each. Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, are you sure you have your `startdate` and `enddate` set correctly, ie. mixed up? More information on your data would let us see where the problems lie

Comment: @Anzel **datefrom** has the same format as **dateto** of *YYYY-MM-DD*.
**startdate** has the same format as **enddate** as you may see from my code above.

I can query in mongodb with **new Date("2014-4-1")**, but when I wrote this in python, it prompted error for invalid syntax for *new Date()* in python. That meant I tried to tell mongo I would like to use this function by means of python, but I failed to do so.

Any idea?

Comment: In order to help you, you need to show more of your code, what values exactly in your code like `datefrom` and `dateto`, how you generate them etc., also `new Date(...)` is merely javascript datetime object whereas in pymongo we can use `datetime(...)` for query. Since you are not able to query even with datetime in python (as you said you tried), I suspect the error lies in somewhere else.

Comment: @Anzel I updated my code. Could you spare a few minutes in reading it and help me? Thank you. As for your suggestion on using 'datetime(...)', did you mean to use datetime() only, but not datetime.datetime()?

Comment: I have provided an answer according to your code. There are 2 mistakes I can see. Please see if that helps. For datetime, I really meant datetime.datetime <-- I'm just being lazy not to type it as per our mutual understanding :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems here, you are trying to call `find` on a **Database** object, also you need to query with the `datetime.datetime` object for `$gte` and `$lt` to work properly in mongodb.

```
def query_data(IP,datefrom,dateto):
    conn = pymongo.MongoClient(IP)
    db = conn.mymongo

    # time.mktime will only return a float point number
    # what you really need are the datetime.datetime objects
    startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(datefrom,'%Y-%m-%d')
    enddate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateto,'%Y-%m-%d')

    # you need to call find method on collection, not database object
    cursor = db['your_collection'].find({'username':'test','created':{'$gte':startdate,'$lt':enddate}})
    print cursor.count()
    ...
```

I haven't tested it but it should then work as expected, and hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I will try it tomorrow when I am in office room. I was using time.strptime last year, and I got the data as I required.

for db['collection'] here, I may make mistake. Anyway, I will let you know if I work through tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem, either. I correct my code with yours exactly. It returns none results.

My pymongo is of version 3.0.1. Can you tell me your pymongo's version, and give your test result with your code, please? Thank you.

Comment: @Victor.Li, are you sure the username actually exists in your collection? Can you go to mongo shell and try query just `db.collection.find({'username':'test'})` and post your result? The reason using datetime/time isn't working means either your dates stored in mongo aren't exactly `ISODate` object, or the records aren't exist in your collection.

Comment: I am sure the user_name exists, and I do find results either by user_name or by datefrom & dateto from my mongodb.

The datetime showed in mongodb is ISODate.

Currently, I use alternative method, that is firstly obtain results by usr_name, then iterate them and check the datetime. 

If you know there is a better way to solve this puzzle, please post here and let us know. Cheers.

Comment: @Victor.Li, you keep asking for help but also at the same time assuming other parts of your code works perfectly fine, that's something we cannot help as in this case there is definitely something wrong within your data. You **NEED** to show your mongo shell results and how exactly the data is modelled.

Comment: @Victor.Li, also as you said, you're sure `user_name` exists, is that means you're querying the wrong field <-- `username`?

Comment: Really I thank you for your kindess.

I confirm that I can obtain data with your code in my local machine (I restored data to my local mongodb via exported bson file from server).

Previously I could not obtain data with your code while querying data from server.

Comment: btw: the field name is *user_name* in server. I did not use this one in my post. But I am sure the original code has no this kind of naive mistake. The things chaged are the Mongo database and server, I guess you were right about the **format of datetime** in the server where it possibly stored datatime in different format but isoformat.

Finally, I confirm that your code is definited working on my local MongoDB where it stores datetime in ISO format (I think it is otherwise I could not get results). Therefore, probably the puzzling stuff is that the datetime format in server is different.

Comment: @Victor.Li, glad you have it figured out. Just wondering why you would have 2 different formats in local and server. Anyhow, good luck with your journey!

Comment: just for test, i was really lost for finding reason. I still wonder that mongo used different datetime format from 2 years ago... I hope I am wrong.